# Create a table with model in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, foreach, null

I am trying to build a table in my view with values from the model. My model in the foreach loop is null. Is there something I could be missing in my controller?

My View (cshtml)

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.BookModel>
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bookName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var b in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.bookName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.Author)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about the action in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I test the view,it's ok.So I am afraid you didn't pass the data from controller to view,or the data you passed is null.Here is a demo worked:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Book()
        {
            List<BookModel> list = new List<BookModel> { new BookModel { bookName = "book1", Author = "author1" }, new BookModel { bookName = "book2", Author = "author2" }, new BookModel { bookName = "book3", Author = "author3" } };
            return View(list);
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<BookModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Book";
}

<h1>Book</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bookName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var b in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.bookName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => b.Author)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Result:
[image]